# Rocksmith 2014 Remastered crashed for no apparrent reason

Tags: steam, technical-issues, rocksmith-2014

Since the release of Rocksmith+ and the update to Rocksmith 2014 Remastered, I am unable to play RS2014R normally as it often opens for a few seconds and then suddenly closes.

1. I tried to close all other programs that have something to do with audio (Spotify, Discord), but nothing works.
2. Also pulling random cables and devices out (USB sticks, potrable HDDs, audio devices, power connector) doesn't work (it looked just like the power connector was at fault, due to being close to the two USB2.0 ports, because RS "was open" a little bit longer - haven't actually measured it).
3. Then I tried to remove all devices including the hidden ones under the device manager menu.
   I don't blame Windows 10 (22H2) but Ubisoft for the situation since all of this happened during Sept 6th update. What I would like, is to play CDLC and use RSMods (currently all disabled). I used [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/rocksmith/comments/xa49mq/important_update_coming_to_rocksmith_2014/) instructions to solve the issues regarding the Steam Update. Here are the RS.ini file and the app manifest:

```
{
 "appid"     "221680"
 "universe"      "1"
 "LauncherPath"      "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Steam\\steam.exe"
 "name"      "Rocksmith® 2014 Edition - Remastered"
 "StateFlags"        "4"
 "installdir"        "Rocksmith2014"
 "LastUpdated"       "1664297153"
 "SizeOnDisk"        "6978074275"
 "StagingSize"       "0"
 "buildid"       "6696987"
 "LastOwner"     "removed"
 "UpdateResult"      "0"
 "BytesToDownload"       "1383106512"
 "BytesDownloaded"       "1383106512"
 "BytesToStage"      "2022593278"
 "BytesStaged"       "2022593278"
 "TargetBuildID"     "6696987"
 "AutoUpdateBehavior"        "1"
 "AllowOtherDownloadsWhileRunning"       "2"
 "ScheduledAutoUpdate"       "0"
 "InstalledDepots"
 {
     "221681"
     {
         "manifest"      "4556485830000690187"
         "size"      "6899047079"
     }
     "248750"
     {
         "manifest"      "2739897805398630095"
         "size"      "11812992"
         "dlcappid"      "248750"
     }
     "492986"
     {
         "manifest"      "7804629250983963736"
         "size"      "10718520"
         "dlcappid"      "492986"
     }
     "492987"
     {
         "manifest"      "3550249174033879465"
         "size"      "9588262"
         "dlcappid"      "492987"
     }
     "492988"
     {
         "manifest"      "1649488964388286072"
         "size"      "7515464"
         "dlcappid"      "492988"
     }
     "492989"
     {
         "manifest"      "6468772442248310332"
         "size"      "9986500"
         "dlcappid"      "492989"
     }
     "509630"
     {
         "manifest"      "5606945270337208326"
         "size"      "10202026"
         "dlcappid"      "509630"
     }
     "509631"
     {
         "manifest"      "2604784316413543435"
         "size"      "10317338"
         "dlcappid"      "509631"
     }
     "753803"
     {
         "manifest"      "4841411533323986442"
         "size"      "8886094"
         "dlcappid"      "753803"
     }
 }
 "InstallScripts"
 {
     "221681"        "UPlay\\uplay_installscript.vdf"
 }
 "SharedDepots"
 {
     "228983"        "228980"
     "228990"        "228980"
 }
 "UserConfig"
 {
     "betakey"       "previous_version"
     "language"      "english"
 }
 "MountedConfig"
 {
     "betakey"       "previous_version"
     "language"      "english"
 }
}
```

.ini file:

```
EnableMicrophone=1
ExclusiveMode=0
LatencyBuffer=4
ForceDefaultPlaybackDevice=1
ForceWDM=0
ForceDirectXSink=0
DumpAudioLog=0
MaxOutputBufferSize=0
RealToneCableOnly=0
Win32UltraLowLatencyMode=1
[Renderer.Win32]
ShowGamepadUI=0
ScreenWidth=0
ScreenHeight=0
Fullscreen=2
VisualQuality=1
RenderingWidth=0
RenderingHeight=0
EnablePostEffects=1
EnableShadows=1
EnableHighResScope=1
EnableDepthOfField=1
EnablePerPixelLighting=1
MsaaSamples=4
DisableBrowser=0
[Net]
UseProxy=1
```

How to solve this problem and set everything up for RS to use CDLC and mods?

Comment: Have you tried verifying the game files through Steam? It may not work, but it's simple enough to try at least.

Comment: The only "problematic" file is the one that enables CDLCs to work.

Comment: What's the max CDLC count the game supports?'

Comment: To be sure: you've switched to the beta branch for Rocksmith 2014, right? It's the first thing linked in the pinned answer in your Reddit Q/A, named "Beta Opt In".

Comment: Yes, I switched to the beta branch, but read that the issues got resolved

Comment: Ok, because it worked for me after switching to the branch. But when it got resolved, does it mean it now works for you?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the issues for the CDLC and RSmods got resolved in the last update. I'll check later and respond.